# HDI: Check the "in-stock" status of an item on a web site in bash?

Tags: bash, scrape, webstore

I'm having a hell of a time catching an item in-stock on a web site.  I keep missing it by about a half hour or so.

How can I pull the contents of the Nikon store page ( http://shop.nikonusa.com/store/nikonusa/en_US/pd/productID.249538300 ) and email an alert to myself (address@gmail.com) when the grey "where to buy" button has been replaced with the yellow "shop now" button ( which can be seen here: http://shop.nikonusa.com/store/nikonusa/en_US/pd/productID.226487200 ).  Is this possible from a bash script, or is it too complex?

Thank you!

Comment: may not be too complex, but likely illegal for the terms-of-service on the website. You'll get banned within a week (maybe less, depending on how fast you run you loop.). Think about it before for doing this. All that said, good luck getting a deal on your camera of dreams.

Comment: Just for the record, this isn't a dealsite or anything -- it's the manufacturer's website and the camera is priced at MSRP (given that it's Nikon's own site).  It's just sold out all the damn time and they don't update the stock status on a predictable timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) to grab the web page then grep to search for the alt text of the button...

```
#!/bin/bash
#D800
x=$( curl -s http://shop.nikonusa.com/store/nikonusa/en_US/pd/productID.249538300 | grep 'alt="Buy Now"')
#D7000 (for testing)
#x=$( curl -s http://shop.nikonusa.com/store/nikonusa/en_US/pd/productID.226487200 | grep 'alt="Buy Now"')
if [ ! -n "$x" ]
then
    echo Not Available
    exit 1
fi
echo "Get clicking" | mail -s "D800 Available" you@example.com
```

Comment: Your answer was good, and very close to what I did.  I ended up uglying something together with wget.

Comment: Also wanted to add that it was an ordeal for me to put this together, but you made it look easy.  :]

Comment: In your 

if [ ! -n "$x" ] , is ! -n equivalent to -z?  Is there any benefit to using ! -n over -z?  Thanks!

example,

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uglying something together with wget.

If anyone runs into the same problem, semi-sanitized code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ ! -f mailready ]
do
sleep 450
echo -e "\n Trying wget [URLHERE]"
wget -N [URLHERE]
        if grep -q buy-now [Downloaded URLfile]
        then
                echo -e "\n Buy now button found at [URL, DATE]\" > scriptbuffer
                cat mailheader scriptbuffer > mailready
                cat mailready| msmtp RECIPIENT@gmail.com
                echo -e "\nBuy-now button found... ending"
        else
                echo -e "\nNo Buy-now button found"
        fi
done
```

It worked incredibly well for me not knowing what the hell I was doing.  I set it up to check about every 7 minutes, and after two or three hours, I was able to place my order.